# JQuery can't parse this HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Context: Highcharts, jQuery 1.9.1

I'm getting a `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:` out of the following HTML and JavaScript `$.get`-ed from our own site.

What's jQuery complaining about? If we execute Demo2_SP_plunkerPartial.prx in a browser, it works fine. (.prx is the extension of an in-house SSL.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<body>
<div>
  <div id="content">
    content from the partial
  </div>
    <div>Some other content</div>
    <script>
      alert('this is the alert from the partial')
    </script>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart : {
      zoomType : 'xy'
    },
    title : {
      text : ' '
    },
    legend : {
      align : 'center',
      verticalAlign : 'bottom'
    },
    xAxis : [{
        categories : ['0-100', '101-200', '201-300', '301-400', '401-500', '501-600', '601-700', '701-801', '901-1000', '1001-2000', '2001-5000', '5000+']
      }
    ],
    yAxis : [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels : {
          style : {
            color : '#89A54E'
          }
        },
        title : {
          text : 'Customers',
          style : {
            color : '#89A54E'
          }
        }
      }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title : {
          text : 'Value ($)',
          style : {
            color : '#4572A7'
          }
        },
        labels : {
          style : {
            color : '#4572A7'
          }
        },
        opposite : true
      }
    ],
    tooltip : {
      shared : true
    },
    series : [{
        name : 'Value ($)',
        color : '#4572A7',
        type : 'column',
        yAxis : 1,
        data : [52250, 195985, 512810, 318107.5, 1287202.5, 362520, 80037.5, 290510, 85975, 1403007.5, 1248727.5, 1025857.5, 172330]

      }, {
        name : 'Customers',
        color : '#89A54E',
        type : 'column',
        data : [550, 1032, 1918, 842, 2712, 639, 121, 389, 101, 1477, 841, 354, 24]
      }
    ]
  });
});
</SCRIPT>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the js code I'm using to get and parse the page:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('Demo2_SP_plunkerPartial.prx', function(result){
        try {
            $result = $(result);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        $result.find('#content').appendTo('#new_content');
        $result.find('script').appendTo('#new_content');
    }, 'html');
});
```

Comment: Should `$result = $(result);` be `var $result = $(result);` ?

Comment: it looks like the jQuery parser is not liking the value of `result`... can you try `var $result = $($.trim(result));`

Comment: [Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yz6T4/2/) - [Fix](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yz6T4/1/)

Comment: But what results returns you, could you paste it?

Answer (score 1):

I've run a small test of your code and it seems functional to me, are you sure the server isn't running some kind of parsing before giving you the "GET" response?

[Here is my test](http://embed.plnkr.co/YGR2xm/preview), the chart seems to work.